# iScroll preventing vertical scroll

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, iscroll, pinchzoom, vertical-scrolling

I implemented iScroll 4 (and 5) to use the pinch zoom function on an image in my Phonegap app with Jquery Mobile. It worked, but now it prevents vertical scrolling.

I just used the included JS file and this script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myScroll;

    function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { zoom:true });
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
</script>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

just remove this line

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```